# String formatting Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, string-formatting

I have an array that displays Date and Conversion. I want to add +"%" after conversion but i cant get it to work. I know as im using an array i cant add this wherever i want. What would be a good way to add + "%" after ConversionRate?

```
function (data) {
    var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    tdata.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    tdata.addColumn('number', 'Conversion');

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var dateStr = data[i].Date.substr(0, 4) + "-" + data[i].Date.substr(4, 2) + "-" + data[i].Date.substr(6, 2);
        tdata.addRow([new Date(dateStr), Number(data[i].ConversionRate)]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [formatters](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters) (I have no experience with this library - a quick google search found that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably work:

```
tdata.addRow([new Date(dateStr), Number(data[i].ConversionRate) + "%"]);
```

But you might have to replace:

```
tdata.addColumn('number', 'Conversion');
```

With:

```
tdata.addColumn('string', 'Conversion');
```

---

Or, a better option, as [Jamiec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219661/jamiec) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062584/string-formating-javascript#comment35241924_23062584), would be to use the `formatter`:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({suffix: '%'});
formatter.format(tdata, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried your first suggestion. That's why i thought it was strange. Changing to string gave some errors as im using Google Charts to display the data. I have do it in someother way

Comment: @KristofferAndersson: Did you try my second suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

Extend javascript's `String` object...

Like this:

```
String.prototype.withPct = function(){
  return this + '%';
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
var pct = '9';
var withPercent = pct.withPct();
```

`withPercent` will be: `'9%'`

But it looks like you might want to extend Number, in which case, you would:

```
Number.prototype.withPct = function(){
  return this + '%';
};
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/LUDmp/)

Comment: Sorry, how rude of me. [Extending built-in objects is bad pracice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice) also You don't describe how to apply this solution to the actual problem.

Comment: ugh... actually, where i said "then use it like this:" describes how to apply it. also, it's not bad practice... at all. That's how prototypal/prototypical inheritance words. All object literals are created via Object.prototype .

Comment: This was not the best worded or explained question, but it's clearly about the use of `google.visualization.DataTable`. Your answer needed to explain how to get that data table rendering onscreen with your code.